# Python-Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Given this code:

```
match = re.search(r'b\w+', 'foobar') =>  found, match.group() == "bar"
```

I think that the match group should be "foobar" since there are no alphanumeric characters that appear in front or behind it. Why is it not so?

Answer (score 4):

Since it will treat `b\w+` as any character that is started from `b` character and will match `bar` instead of whole word.

Use `\b` as word boundary.

Change

```
b\w+
```

To:

```
\b\w+
```

---

Use `^` and `$` to match whole line for example `^foo$` will match `foo` only.

- `^` assert position at start of a line
- `foo` matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
- `$` assert position at end of a line

Test your regex pattern online at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oS9pR2/3).

Comment: ok i got it. Another question related is  from docs.python.org r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'. However, that works for '3foo' but not 'foo3'. I dont quite understand the word boundary expression in regex

Comment: Enclose it inside the `^` and `$` to match whole string. `^foo$` Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS9pR2/3) and there is no need to use word boundary in this case. For code click on *Code Generator* in the demo site.

Answer (score 0):

`re.search()` moves up the string looking for the pattern (unlike `re.match()`, which must match from the first character).